# Asp.net core 3.0 on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: asp.net-core, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

AWS Elastic Beanstalk seems to support asp.net core up to version 2.2.6 (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/relnotes/release-2019-08-08-windows.html)

We want to use asp.net core 3.0
Is there a way to do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

**Edit 30/10/2019**

Elastic Beanstalk now supports .NET Core 3.0 so no need for any workarounds

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/10/aws-elastic-beanstalk-adds-support-for-php-7-3-and-net-core-3-0/

---

You can `dockerize` your ASP.Net Core 3.0 application, zip it up and upload to Elastic Beanstalk.

Dockerize ASP.Net Core - https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/dotnetcore/

Use docker with Elastic Beanstalk-https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker.html

Answer (score 2):

I have had success hosting asp.net core 3.0 apps on elastic beanstalk iis hosts by adding a runtime identifier to the project targeting win-x64 as described in this blog post (I know it is for .NET core 2.1 but same works for .NET core 3.0)
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/net-core-2-1-and-aws/

I hope this works out for you.